# How do I enable the Ruby 2.3 `--enable-frozen-string-literal` globally in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.3

I am building a greenfield Rails application on top of Ruby 2.3, and I would like all Rails commands (e.g. `rails s`, `rails c`) and all Ruby commands (e.g. `rake do:something`) to use the new immutable-String functionality introduced in Ruby 2.3.  (See, e.g. https://wyeworks.com/blog/2015/12/1/immutable-strings-in-ruby-2-dot-3/)

So, how do I pass that lovely `--enable-frozen-string-literal` Ruby option down to Ruby in all possible contexts where some command I issue bottoms out in Ruby?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I know, best way to do it is setting environment variable like followings:

```
export RUBYOPT=--enable-frozen-string-literal
```

or

```
setenv RUBYOPT --enable-frozen-string-literal
```

However, don't try it right now. It simply doesn't work because some codes in Bundler gem are attempting to modify frozen String. Wait until they fix the problem.

Comment: Bundler should be able to support frozen string literals [since v1.12](http://bundler.io/v1.12/whats_new.html). If it still doesn't work, file an issue like [this](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4520).

Comment: More portable: `RUBYOPT=--enable-frozen-string-literal; export RUBYOPT` will work with `/bin/sh` on FreeBSD, bash, zsh, fish, etc.

Comment: what about if gems are trying to modify strings? It's probably not common but I'm sure it happens somewheere.

Comment: Definitely not ready for production :) `There was an error while trying to load the gem 'haml'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: can't modify frozen String`

Comment: Not even Rails v5.0.2 handles it: a rather fresh app errors with `…actionview-5.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb:16:in 'force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)` on startup.

Comment: rails 5.2 fails for me too :/